# understanding serializable - file persistence - jar

Tags: java, serialization

I was told to create an app that serializes and persists files which contain object information.
its hard for me to understand how this is possible since the app hypothetically speaking should be used in more than one  pc,  thus my questions:

1. how can I create a .jar  with all the new files uploaded to their correspondent directories and be able to update the information?
2. Is it possible to  programmatically re-open a .jar update information and "close the jar" ? if so where can I search for this to study it.
3. if i'm able to de-serialize and update files, should I create one file per object ? wouldn't this be a waste of space ?
4. is it possible to serialize several objects into one file ?

Thanks.

Edit: The goal of this app is to serialize instead of using a DB to persist any `Object` information and make an executable from this, if  and when i create the executable file, shouldn't I create .jar from the files SERIALIZED ?  or creating the .jar after serializing for me to be able to use this as a library ? ??

Comment: "object information" as in java.lang.Object? If so, what does this have to do with jars? Jars contain class files, not serialized objects (although they technically could, but I'm almost sure that is not what you want). Please be clear on what your actual goal is.

Comment: @Simon Fischer, The goal of this app is to serialize instead of using a DB to persist any `Object` information and make an executable from this, if  and when i create the executable file, shouldn't I create .jar from the files SERIALIZED ?  or creating the .jar after serializing for me to be able to use this as a library ? ??